# R Accessing deeper level in nested list

Tags: r, list, subset

I have the feeling that this question has been answered somewhere but I couldn't find an example similar enough. My problem is as follows.

I have a list `ls` which contains 3 lists `agb` `gpp` and `npp`. Each list is in turn made of 3 vectors. You can recreate such a list by doing

```
ls = list()
elem1=list()
elem2=list()
elem3=list()
elem1$vect1 = c(1,2,3)
elem1$vect2 = c(2,3,4)
elem1$vect3 = c(3,4,5)
elem2$vect1 = c(1,2,3)
elem2$vect2 = c(2,3,4)
elem2$vect3 = c(3,4,5)
elem3$vect1 = c(1,2,3)
elem3$vect2 = c(2,3,4)
elem3$vect3 = c(3,4,5)
ls$gpp = elem1
ls$npp = elem2
ls$agb = elem3
```

So that

```
str(ls)    
List of 3
 $ gpp:List of 3
  ..$ vect1: num [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ vect2: num [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ vect3: num [1:3] 3 4 5
 $ npp:List of 3
  ..$ vect1: num [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ vect2: num [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ vect3: num [1:3] 3 4 5
 $ agb:List of 3
  ..$ vect1: num [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ vect2: num [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ vect3: num [1:3] 3 4 5
```

Now if I want to access the `gpp` for the first `vect` I just do `ls$gpp[["vect1"]]`. If I want all the `gpp` I just do `ls$gpp`. But what if I have to access all first indexes (`gpp`, `agb`, `npp`) for the `vect1` element? Something like `ls[[]][["vect1"]]`where the first empty set of square brackets would stand for every sublist of `ls`.

Comment: Like `lapply(ls, "[[", "vect1")`?

Comment: I often saw the `lapply` instruction but never quite used it. Didn't expect it to be that simple. Thanks. (I am not sure the question is worth preserving but if you want you can post you comment as an answer)

Comment: You could also use `Map("[[", ls, "vect1")` if you want to save a few keystrokes. I'm looking for a duplicate question; I think I've seen this asked before.

Comment: Most people would write code like this `lapply(ls, function(x) x$vect1) or lapply(ls, function(x) x[[1]])` Calling the subset operator seems a bit less readable.